# Boost.Log macro expansion and conditional ternary operator

Tags: c++, boost, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "test Boost.Log";
  true ? 0 : BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "this fails";
}
```

Compilation command:

```
clang++ main.cc -o main \
  -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_thread -lboost_system -pthread --static
```

Above throws an error:

```
main2.cc:5:18: error: expected expression
      true ? 0 : BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "this fails";
                 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/log/trivial.hpp:113:5: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL'
    BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS(::boost::log::trivial::logger::get(),\
    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:317:5: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS'
    BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS_INTERNAL(logger, BOOST_LOG_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_NAME(_boost_log_record_), params_seq)
    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:306:5: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS_INTERNAL'
    for (::boost::log::record rec_var = (logger).open_record((BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(params_seq))); !!rec_var;)\
    ^
1 error generated.
```

The above is a problem I've isolated when trying to create a macro:

```
#define LOG_IF(lvl, condition) \
  !(condition) ? 0 : BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)
```

When run g++ to expand macros (`g++ -E -C -P -o pre.cc main.cc`):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  for (::boost::log::record _boost_log_record_4 = (::boost::log::trivial::logger::get()).open_record((::boost::log::keywords::severity = ::boost::log::trivial::info)); !!_boost_log_record_4;) ::boost::log::aux::make_record_pump((::boost::log::trivial::logger::get()), _boost_log_record_4).stream() << "test Boost.Log";
  true ? 0 : for (::boost::log::record _boost_log_record_5 = (::boost::log::trivial::logger::get()).open_record((::boost::log::keywords::severity = ::boost::log::trivial::info)); !!_boost_log_record_5;) ::boost::log::aux::make_record_pump((::boost::log::trivial::logger::get()), _boost_log_record_5).stream() << "this fails";
}
```

The reason why it fails it's obvious (form compilation error). But at this point I have no idea how to work around it.

Comment: Why not use the `if` statement? `if (condition) BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)`

Comment: Thanks @KennyTM I somehow overlooked this beautifully simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

As @KennyTM suggested:

```
#define LOG_IF(lvl, condition) \
  if (condition) BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)
```

works pretty well (Thanks!).

However I'm still interested whether conditional expression can be used with Boost logging macros.

Answer (score 0):

The answer's right there in the error message you pasted. `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` expands, after a couple of intermediate steps, to a `for` *statement*. The ternary operator forms an *expression*, and statements cannot form a direct part of expressions in basic C-family syntax, so this fails. The `for` is integral to the operation of the statement (it provides a means to do something "after" the part on the left, either by inserting extra statements at the front or by creating a scope block), so simply rewriting the macro isn't easily done.

If you want a quick and hacky suggestion, you could just use GCC statement expressions, or possibly lambdas (noisier but standard):

```
true ? ({0;}) : ({ BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "this fails"; });
```

If you want a more ...something... solution that looks roughly like the original, you could try to wrap it in a containing object:

```
#define LOG_TRIVIAL_EXPR(inf) TrivLogger([](std::string msg){ BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(inf) << msg; })

template<typename M>
class TrivLogger {
    typedef std::function<void(std::string)> F;
    F thunk;
    TrivLogger(F th) : thunk(th) {}
    TrivLogger<M> operator<<(std::string msg) {
        thunk(msg); return this;
    }
}

//...
true ? 0 : LOG_TRIVIAL_EXPR(info) << "this should work";
```

(To be honest I have no idea whether I got that right...)